# Loading in 256bit vector register in AVX2 Haswell processor

Tags: cpu-architecture, avx2

I want to load a `256 bit YMM` register with 32 values, each of length 1 byte.  All the intrinsic I looked into load either `double word`, i.e., `4 byte` integers or `quad word`, i.e., `8 byte` values.
How to load data of size lesser than these?
Is there any mnemonic which does this but don't has a equivalent intrinsic?

Answer (score 1):

I don't think there is a way to gather bytes only.  But it sounds to me like you need to rethink your problem.  Is this pixel data?  For Example RGBA values?  If so, maybe you can change your application so it read/writes out for example RRRRGGGGBBBB (SSE).  Then you don't have to gather bytes.  You can read in 128/256 bits at once and that will be the most efficient use of SIMD.

Note that you may gain efficiency by using short int operations.  I mean extent to 16bits and use 16bit integer SSE/AVX instructions.

Here is an example of bi-linear interpolation with SSE which reads in integers of four bytes (RGBA), and extends them to 16bits.  This is faster then extending them to 32bits. The SSE3 example converts RGBARGBARGBARGBA to RRRRGGGGBBBB. 
http://fastcpp.blogspot.no/2011/06/bilinear-pixel-interpolation-using-sse.html

Answer (score 1):

You can simply use the [_mm256_load_si256](http://software.intel.com/sites/products/documentation/studio/composer/en-us/2011Update/compiler_c/intref_cls/common/intref_avx_load_si256.htm) intrinsic with a cast. This intrinsic corresponds to the VMOVDQA instruction.

Here is the code to read bytes from memory, and to store them in memory.

```
char raw[32] __attribute__ ((aligned (32)));
__v32qi foo = _mm256_loadu_si256( (__m256i*) raw ); // read raw bytes from memory into avx register
_mm256_store_si256( (__m256i*) raw, foo ); // store contents of avx register into memory
```

You can also load unaligned bytes, using _mm256_loadu_si256 if you prefer.

Answer (score 1):

This is a rather old question but I think what you might want is the `AVX` intrinsic `__m256i _mm256_set_epi8` which takes 32 chars as input parameters.

Answer (score 0):

There is no instruction which broadcasts single byte, but you can use `_mm256_set1_epi8` intrinsic to achieve this effect.

Comment: No. Actually I don't want to broadcast.
I want to load different `bytes` from a base address.

Comment: Then `_mm256_load_si256`/`_mm256_loadu_si256` is what you need.

Comment: My question was not written explicitly. My bad.
Its not that the data is in consecutive memory location.
I want to load `bytes` one by one from different pointers.

Answer (score 0):

Where do you expect the 32 pointers to come from?  Unless you're wanting to do 32 parallel lookups into a 256-byte lookup table, you don't really have space in the source operand to write the addresses required for the load.

I think you have to do four 8x32-bit gather operations and then merge the results; the gather operation supports unaligned accesses so you could load from an address adjusted to get the target byte in the right place within the YMM register, then just AND with masks and OR to merge.